Find correlation function $\langle R^2(t_1) R^2(t_2)\rangle$ for 2d stochastic dynamics of polymer
The problem:
Consider 2d stochastic dynamics
\begin{equation}
\partial_t R_\alpha = \sigma_{\alpha \beta} R_\beta
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\langle \sigma_{\alpha \beta}(t_1) \sigma_{\mu \nu}(t_2) \rangle = A (3 \delta_{\alpha \mu} \delta_{\beta \nu} - \delta_{\alpha \beta}\delta_{\mu \nu} - \delta_{\alpha \nu}\delta_{\beta \mu})\delta(t_1-t_2)
\end{equation}
Find correlation function $\langle R^2(t_1) R^2(t_2)\rangle$ , $t_2 > t_1 $, $R_{\alpha}(0) = R_0 n_\alpha$, where $n_\alpha$ is unit vector
A solution attempt:
I was able only calculate same time correlation functions by solving equation exactly
\begin{equation}
R_\alpha = U_{\alpha \beta} R_0 n_\beta \qquad U = \hat{T} exp[\int_0^t \hat{\sigma}(t') dt'],
\end{equation}
where $\hat{T} exp$ means ordered exponentional. I then decompose $\langle (R^2(t+ \Delta t))^2 \rangle$ , leaving only first order of $\Delta t$.
I've obtained differential equation for same time correlation function. Solution is $R_0^4 \exp[2 4 A t]$. However, i am confused what to do, when $t_1 \not = t_2$.
I also managed to find distribution for $\rho = \ln[ R(t) /R_0]$. Here $R(t)$ means modulus of vector $\overline{R}$.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}(\rho) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi A t}} \exp[- \frac{(\rho - 2 A t)^2}{4 A t}]
\end{equation}

I think that more details are needed. What do the function mean, $R, \sigma$? How many coordinates $\alpha$ do you have? $\alpha = 1,2,3$? Also what is stochastic, all the components of $R$ and $\sigma$?

It seems like then square function can be decomposed in the Taylor series and the $\sigma$ correlation appear and differentiation goes from the $\partial_t R_\alpha$ equation. So that it might be a way.

It might be fruitful to introduce why you want to solve this problem, since people might help you better

Ok, looking to the equations, both $R$ and $\sigma$ are stochastic but dependent on each other

Do $R$ and $\sigma& have a special statistics? The result might be simpler.

I mentioned in heading that it is 2d problem, so $\alpha = 1,2$. Here stochastic means that $\sigma$ is random matrix with known correlation function. Angle brackets mean that $R^2(t_1) R^2(t_2)$ is averaged over $\sigma$'s disorder. I added more i've accomplished in solving this problem

Are you sure there is no time dependence on the correlation of $\sigma$? It looks weird, there might be a delta function of time or something.

You are right. I just missed to insert that $\sigma$ is $\delta$ correlated

by the way, you wrote 2d stochastic dynamics, it sounded like second stochastic dynamics and not 2 dimensional stochastic dynamics. And the first term, to my limited knowledge, means that there are several stochastic processes interconnected, this is why my question about the number of dimensions.

In such problems we also need to know $\langle\sigma\rangle$. Is this quantity equal to zero in this problem?

Yes mean $\sigma$ is zero

It is important to mention in the question that the expected value of sigma is zero then. I tried edit this information in the post but it was rejected and I am not agree this is important information since if it is not zero the calculation is different.

I think that you probably already know everything necessary to obtain a solution. The form of the equations for $R_\alpha$ and the fact that $\sigma$ is $\delta$-correlated imply that the random process is Markov and homogeneous in the following sense: for $t_2>t_1$ the ratio
$$
\frac{R(t_2)}{R(t_1)} \equiv e^\rho
$$
does not depend on $R(t_1)$ and on the evolution for $t<t_1$. Then the following formula is valid for the required average
$$
\langle R^2(t_1)R^2(t_2)\rangle = \langle R^4(t_1)\left(\frac{R(t_2)}{R(t_1)}\right)^2\rangle = \langle R^4(t_1)\rangle\langle e^{2\rho}\rangle
$$
Now, if you have the correct formulas for $\langle R^4(t_1)\rangle$ and ${\cal P}(\rho)$, you only need to calculate the following integral
$$
\langle e^{2\rho}\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi At}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\rho-2At)^2}{4At}+2\rho \right)\ d\rho
$$
for $t = t_2-t_1$.
Update. Xian-Zu, you did not show how you arrived at the formulas for $\langle R^4(t)\rangle$ and ${\cal P}(\rho)$. So unless there is a guarantee that this result is absolutely correct, I would assume that there is an error in your calculations. My analysis showed that there are the following time dependencies
$$
\langle R^2(t)\rangle = R_0^2e^{4At},\quad
\langle R^4(t)\rangle = R_0^4 e^{12At},\quad
\langle \ln(R(t))\rangle = \ln(R_0) + At,
$$
which are consistent with
$$
{\cal P}(\rho) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi At}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\rho-At)^2}{2At}\right).
$$
I also derived the following equation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t_2}\langle R^2(t_2) R^2(t_1)\rangle = 4A \langle R^2(t_2) R^2(t_1)\rangle
$$
for $t_2>t_1$, from which we get
$$
\langle R^2(t_2) R^2(t_1)\rangle = e^{4A(t_2-t_1)}\langle R^2(t_1) R^2(t_1)\rangle = e^{4A(t_2-t_1)}e^{12At_1}R_0^4
$$
The last formula is consistent with what I wrote earlier, it can be written as
$$
\langle R^2(t_2) R^2(t_1)\rangle = \langle R^4(t_1)\rangle \langle e^{2\rho(t)}\rangle_{t = t_2-t_1}.
$$
Addition 1. Now I see that my and your formulas differ by a factor of 2. Perhaps you took the following equality
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \delta (t_1 - t)dt = 1,
$$
and I think that the correct one is:
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \delta (t_1 - t)dt = \frac12.
$$
Addition 2. According to Xian-Tzu's commentary, when calculating $\partial\langle R^2(t)\rangle/\partial t$, it is necessary to use the correlation $\langle \sigma_{\alpha\rho}(t_1)\sigma_{\rho\beta}(t_2)$ . This expression, however, implies the sum
$$
\sum_{\rho = 1}^2\langle \sigma_{\alpha\rho}(t_1)\sigma_{\rho\beta}(t_2)\rangle
$$
which is equal to zero by virtue of the definition of $\sigma$ correlations in the problem statement. We have
$$
\sum_{\rho = 1}^2\langle \sigma_{\alpha\rho}(t_1)\sigma_{\rho\beta}(t_2)\rangle = A\delta(t_2-t_1)\sum_{\rho=1}^2\left(3\delta_{\alpha\rho}\delta_{\rho\beta}-\delta_{\alpha\rho}\delta_{\rho\beta}-\delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\rho\rho}\right) = 
$$
$$
=A\delta(t_2-t_1)\left(3\delta_{\alpha\beta}-\delta_{\alpha\beta}-\delta_{\alpha\beta}\sum_{\rho=1}^21\right) = 0.
$$
Therefore, the equation for $\langle R^2(t)\rangle$ takes the form
$$
\frac{\partial\langle R^2(t)\rangle}{\partial t} = 4A\langle R^2(t)\rangle.
$$
I think that when solving this problem it is better to use the following forms of equalities
$$
\dot{R}_\alpha(t) = \sum_\beta\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(t)R_\beta(t),
\quad R^2 = \sum_\alpha R_\alpha R_\alpha
$$

Formula for mean $R^4$ can be also obtained through distribution function - $\langle R_0^4e^{4 \rho} \rangle $. However, your suggestion is wrong, unfortunately.

@Xian-Zu Do you know the answer?

Unfortunately, no. Professor, who gave me this problem, replied that it is wrong answer.
I obtained same result as you and for limit cases $t_1 = t_2$ and $t_1 =0$ it gives correct answers. That's why i am interrested in solving this problem. For me your answer - legit and i don't know why it is wrong.

@Xian-Zu Did the professor provide any feedback on whether your formulas for $\langle R^4(t)\rangle$ and ${\cal P}(\rho)$ are correct? My analysis gave $\langle R^2(t)\rangle = R_0^2e^{4At}$, which is not consistent with what follows from your ${\cal P}(\rho)$. The correlations of $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}$ are asymmetric across indices, this fact played an important role in my derivation of $\langle R^2(t)\rangle = R_0^2e^{4At}$.

Gec, how do you conclude that if $\sigma$ is delta correleated (and possibly wide sense stationary), then R(t) is Markov process? Is there a property on a time-ordered exponent or something like that?

@PierrePolovodov, $\vec{R}(t_2)$ depends only on $\vec{R}(t_1)$ and $\sigma(t)$ for $t\in(t_1,t_2)$. Due to the fact that $\sigma$ is delta correlated, $\sigma(t)$ for $t\in(t_1,t_2)$ is uncorrelated with $\sigma(t')$ for $t'<t_1$. The later is related to the way how the process $\vec{R}(t)$ came to $\vec{R}(t_1)$ and this way is irrelevant for the transition from $\vec{R}(t_1)$ to $\vec{R}(t_2)$. Physically, this means that the process is Markov one.

Ok, I see it from the equation $R(t_1) = Texp[\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \hat{\sigma}(\tau) d\tau ] R(t_1)$ where $R(t_2)$ is a new boundary condition

My derivation of  mean square gives coefficent 8
When i expanded ordered exponential i have 3 essential terms

Square of first order $ \int_t^{t+ \Delta t} \int_t^{t+ \Delta t} \langle \sigma_{\alpha \beta} (t_1)\sigma_{\alpha \gamma}(t_2)\rangle dt_1 dt_2 = 4 A \Delta t \delta_{\beta \gamma}$
2 second order terms $\int_t^{t+ \Delta t} \int_t^{t_1}  \langle \sigma_{\alpha \rho} (t_1)\sigma_{\rho \beta}(t_2)\rangle dt_1 dt_2 = 2 A \Delta t\delta_{\alpha \beta}$
All terms finaly give equation: $d\langle R^2\rangle/dt = 8 A \langle R^2\rangle$


@Xian-Zu I see. I think there is mistake here. I agree with what you obtain in1), but in 2) 2 second order terms actually give zero. I'll update my answer.

Effectively your answer is equal to mine, but with subtitution $A \to A/2$. When i calculated i reasoned 2 order terms by pretty physical idea. Average gives $\delta$ function and it works on upper limit of integral $\int_t^t_1 dt_2$. My idea was to say that in this case only half of $\delta$ works.

@Xian-Zu You can't just make a substitution. There are details of the calculations that make the changes necessary. If the answer is correct after the changes and is not before, then these details are important. The fact that only half of the delta function works is written in my answer in Addition 1. In your previous comment arguments were present about why the coefficient in the equation for $<R^2>$ is $8A$. I answered in Addition 2 without mentioning half of delta-function why there actually is $4A$ in equation.

Gec, Xian-Zu, when you calculate correlations like $\langle R^2(t)\rangle$ I understand that you calculate as $\sum R_i R_i$, you use the equation of ordered exponent and decompose it to the series of integrals, is that so? Then you simplify the equation. There are terms type $\langle \sigma \rangle$ which is zero by the definition of process, next terms from on part $R_i(t)$ $\langle \sigma \sigma \rangle$ gives zero because of summing of the Kroneker symbols.

I see that there is a term that will give $4AtR^2(0)$ which is multiplication of "left" and "right" terms with one integral. The question is what you do with other terms: like ones that give $\langle \sigma \sigma \sigma \rangle$, since there is no an equation on these higher order correlations?

It is not clear how you get to the simple correlation equations

@PierrePolovodov In this sort of theory, terms of third and higher orders in $\sigma$ are neglected. You might first want to read about the Langevin equation and its application to the theory of Brownian motion. I have not encountered problems like the one discussed here before, but I see that its solution involves further development of the methods of the ordinary theory of Brownian motion. It is not possible to discuss the calculations involved in the comments. Perhaps you should ask another question to discuss such details.
